# My iphone 4s is not being recognised by my itunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

I have just got the new iphone 4s and when I am trying to sync it with my itunes it is not being recognised.
I have downloaded the new itunes twice so I am sure it is up to date. 
Does anyone have any other solutions I can try?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reinstall the Apple Device manager,

If you are using windows here is the page on [apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1538) that outlines the process below. If you are using [OSX see this page here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1747)

make sure you uninstall all the itunes apps, including device manager, once thats done, download an install iTunes again.

That should all now work.

Comment: sorry, this might sounds really dumb, but I have a macbook so will this still work?

Comment: answer updated for you